# What was the cause of Avatar Wan's death?

Tags: avatar-the-last-airbender, the-legend-of-korra

At the end of "Beginnings, part 2", the scene cuts to a worn down and wounded Wan, in what appears to be a battlefield. The landscape itself looks like a war zone. It is a rough mountainous region with Earth boulders, fire and smoke filling the sky.

Wan has aged and is an old man at this point, and is wearing some sort of armour, implying that he was indeed apart of one the armies. We see him leaning back severely injured on an big disk shaped rock. With lots of Arrows surrounding his body. Wan also appears to be the last one standing.

- What were the factors that contributed to Wan's death?
- How could a power such as the Avatar State fail to protect him?

[image: smoking battlefield]

[image: man surrounded by arrows, leaning on a boulder]

[image: Notice that the soldiers on the left are wearing the same attire and armour as Wan]

Comment: The war that occurred wasn't elaborated much on, because the point of this scene is to illustrate that nobody, not even Wan, can destroy darkness forever - so, naturally, he's going to lose at some point.

Comment: Some speculation: the stone disks seems to depict how the Earth Kingdom (or its precursor) is already founded (the square in the middle of a stone circle) - there is a fair chance that the war that killed Wan is actually the war that separated the world in four nations.

Comment: Old age I guess since he looked very old when he was fighting in what seemed a Earth Kingdom War.

Answer (score 8):

In the sequence you described, Wan is an elderly man participating in what appeared to be a pitched battle with Wan as the last survivor.

To answer the most important question:

- We are not sure what killed Avatar Wan. He was an old man when we see him last. He could have been injured, he could have been tired. He could have simply died from old age. We are left only with the scene of his soul leaving his body preparing to reincarnate into the next Avatar.
- We know the Avatar State does not make you invulnerable to injury. We have seen both Ang and Korra harmed while using the Avatar State. Even if he had been using the Avatar State, he may still have found himself overmatched particularly at his age.
- Being an old man, the Avatar State may have either been too much strain on his body to maintain or he was simply too old to bend the elements without consequence.

**From the Avatar Wiki [Wan Entry](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Wan)**

> As time passed, Wan tried to maintain the balance in the world, urging the different groups of people to coexist peacefully. However, this proved to be a daunting task, one that he would work at his entire lifetime without ever seeing it come to an end. Years later, an armored and elderly Wan laid resting in the aftermath of a battlefield. Before passing away, Wan apologized to Raava for failing to bring peace to the world. However, the light spirit reassured him that they would always be together through all his lifetimes and would never give up. With that, Wan exhaled his last breath and his spirit left his body to be reincarnated, thus beginning the Avatar Cycle.
>
> *Hedrick, Tim (writer) & Graham, Ian (director). (October 18, 2013). "Beginnings, Part 2". The Legend of Korra. Season 1. Episode 20. Nickelodeon.*

Comment: Ah. This would probably explain why Roku and all the avatars prior to him were so against the idea of people from different nations living together a coexisting.

Comment: @Reiko96, I'm not sure what you mean? All of the Avatars shown have worked to resolve conflicts, not to separate people.

Comment: I am referring to Aang and Roku's mentally at the beginning of the promise regarding the harmony restoration movement.